# I get type error when executing a custom built mongoose query, why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get this type error when executing a custom built mongoose query:

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'schema' of undefined]

Query is this:

```
var Query = mongoose.Query;
var query = new Query();
query.collection(Blogpost.collection);
query.findOne({}).exec().then(function (doc) {
    console.dir(doc);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err); //here the error is returned
});
```

When executing a query from a model, it works normally. Why would custom built fail? I have Mongoose version 3.8.0

Comment: Why are you using that syntax? Why not `Model.findOne({})....`?

Comment: I probably don't need it, you are right, I always have model stored in some variable. I just found this in an example in docs and thought I might try it.